# How to get an image from another app's notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating a notification management app and I want to get the contents of notifications which other apps show. currently I use codes like this :

```
statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
```

and this :

```
statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

to read the title and text of notifications. but after a few hours I couldn't find a way to get the image which comes along with the notification's text. for example a profile picture which is showed in Whatsapp's notification. I know it's not the Small or Large icons, I checked a few times.

So if anyone could help in any way, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you use [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to listen to notification from other app.

In you `NotificationService` class, extract icon ressource id in extra `Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON` and access the other app package ressources to get the `Drawable`.

`Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE` contains the large image sent in the notification :

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {

        // a notification is posted

        String pack = statusBarNotification.getPackageName();

        Bundle extras = statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras;

        int iconId = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);

        try {
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            Resources resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(pack);

            Drawable icon = resources.getDrawable(iconId);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {
            // this bitmap contain the picture attachment
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
        }

    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {
        //call when notification is removed
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tested large and extra large icon. I also tried the Extra_Picture you mentioned and didn't succeed. I guess I didn't use it properly. But since it's from another application, how should I address it ? I tried getPackageContext to get their icon and for this extra_picture I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: As I said in my post, I've tried icons and it's not my intention.

Comment: I've been testing with hangout android app, `Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE` holds the picture element. I've re-update my post with `Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE`. You said you haven't succeed with `EXTRA_PICTURE`, can you be more specific ? Try setting an imageView with the bitmap : `iconView.setImageBitmap(bmp)`

Comment: whatever I do this line returns null : `sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)` . for Icons I use `sbnContext = createPackageContext(...)`  and then use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(sbnContext.getResources(), iconInt)` to get it and it works fine. but I don't know how to get the EXTRA_PICTURE using the packageContext because it's not an int. besides it's always null.

Comment: It's not `getString`, this is : `extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)`. It returns an `Object ` that should be cast to `Bitmap`

Comment: It was null too. maybe it happens because WhatsApp did something to secure it's data.

Comment: I tried : `Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);` and `Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);` both return null. I guess I need to use the app's context somehow but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127017/discussion-between-bertrand-martel-and-lord-sepid).

Comment: It worked. thanks a lot. the culprit was "Instant Run" in android studio. I had to uninstall my app and reinstall it to see the new results. I did it like you said using `extras.get(...)`

Comment: the issue is that .. when we clear the app .. after that he app is not able to recognise the incoming notifications .. is there any way to do so .. i think the service stops automatically.