# I can't get the notification image on android 5.1, always return null

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that takes all images sent via whatsapp by notification but the function is apparently not working on older versions of android. Help me please!

```
public String getBase64(Notification notification){
if(bundle.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)){
   // Log.d("Tem foto","notificação");
    String encoded="";

    try {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //base64String = encoded;

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("erro",e.getMessage());
    }

    return encoded;
  }
  else{
    //Log.d("key","não tem key");
    return "";
 }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an image from another app's notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325307/how-to-get-an-image-from-another-apps-notification)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a NotificationListenerService

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification){
    String package = statusBarNotification.getPackageName();
    Bundle extras = statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras;
    try {
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Resources resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(package);
        Drawable icon = resources.getDrawable(iconId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {
        // Here you may get the image
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
    }
}
```